Is tetrad postualte independent of gauge field?
Here is what I know, $g_{\mu \nu} = e^{a}_{\mu} e^{b}_{\nu} \eta_{ab}$ and the tetrad postulate is
\begin{equation}
D_{\rho} e^{a}_{\nu} = \partial_{\rho} e^{a}_{\mu} - \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\rho \nu}e^{a}_{\lambda}+ \omega^{a}_{b \mu} e^{b}_{\nu}=0
\end{equation}
But in case of abelian or non abelian Yang mills, $D_{\mu}$ is different and that should affect the tetrad postulate. In the same spirit what becomes of the statement that gamma matrices are covariantly constant. Or, are we working on different bundles? I am really confused, any help will be appreciated.
Edit: The covariant derivative in flat space-time for abelian gauge field is $D = \gamma^{\mu}(\partial_{\mu} + iA_{\mu})$ and $D \gamma^{\nu} =0$ here using $\partial_{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}$ we get $\gamma^{\mu} A_{\mu} \gamma^{\nu}=0$ what does it mean? I don't understand the underlying mathematical structure

For objects that are uncharged under the gauge group, the covariant derivative does not contain the gauge field.

@Prahar since $e^{a}{\nu}$ is also invarint under gauge transformation, $D{\rho}e^{a}_{\nu}=0$ remains same as well? Also, is there more precise mathematical explanation for the same. Thanks.

As @Prahar's comment pointed out:
The tetrad $e^{a}_{\nu}$ is invariant under the Yang-Mills gauge transformations, such as the $U(1)$ gauge transformation related to $A_{\mu}$. Therefore the covariant derivative of tetrad should NOT contain gauge field $A_{\mu}$.
As a comparison, tetrad $e^{a}_{\nu}$ transforms as a vector (i.e. NOT invariant) under the Lorentz gauge transformation. As a consequence, the covariant derivative of tetrad $D_{\rho} e^{a}_{\nu} = \partial_{\rho} e^{a}_{\mu} - \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\rho \nu}e^{a}_{\lambda}+ \omega^{a}_{b \mu} e^{b}_{\nu}$  DOES contain the Lorentz gauge field (spin connection) $\omega^{a}_{b \mu}$.

Thanks for the clarification
